# Como interpretar o * nesta query

Tags: sql, linq, inner

Tenho aqui uma `query` que, aparentemente, é simples se não fosse pelo facto de ter esses dois `*` ai, que eu não estou conseguindo saber se é `inner join`, `left join` ou algum outro da mesma família.

Preciso transformar essa `query` para `linq to sql`, e o resultado não esta batendo certo. Alguém me ajuda a interpretar isso? Eu fiz `left join` e não bateu certo.

```
select AFENTIDADE.NOMEENTIDADE, NOMEAO, NOMEUTILIZADOR,
MN.DATACRIA, MN.DATAFECHO, MN.NUMFACT,
MN.NUMFOLHA, AESERVICO.TempoEI, HORASA, R.PRECOD
From AEMANUTE MN WITH (NOLOCK), AFENTIDADE WITH (NOLOCK), AREGDOC R WITH (NOLOCK),
UTILIZADORES WITH (NOLOCK), AESERVICO WITH (NOLOCK),  AIAREAORGANICA WITH (NOLOCK)
Where  (MN.CODENTIDADE=AFENTIDADE.CODENTIDADE
And MN.CODAO=AIAREAORGANICA.CODAO
AND MN.CODAO *=R.CODAO
And MN.numfolha=aeservico.numfolha
And MN.numfact *= R.numfact
And aeservico.codutilizador=utilizadores.codutilizador
AND UTILIZADORES.ANULADO IS NULL 
AND
R.coddoc='FM') And 
R.STATUS<>'E' And
MN.IdSituacao=5
--or MN.IdSituacao=5) 
And
LEFT(MN.datafecho, 10) >='2017-04-01' And LEFT(MN.datafecho, 10)  <='2017-04-30' 
ORDER BY  NOMEAO, NOMEUTILIZADOR, AFENTIDADE.NOMEENTIDADE
```

Comment: Da uma olhadinha aqui, acho que é o seu caso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator

Answer (score 2):

A princípio a construção *= é o mesmo que LEFT JOIN.

Construções do tipo

```
-- código #1
SELECT T1.codigo, T2.nome
  from tab1 as T1, tab2 as T2
  where T1.codigo *= T2.codigo;
```

geralmente são convertidas para

```
-- código #2
SELECT T1.codigo, T2.nome
  from tab1 as T1
       left outer join tab2 as T2 on T1.codigo = T2.codigo;
```

Entretanto, o resultado retornado pode ser ligeiramente diferente, dependendo das demais condições envolvidas e do SGBD.

---

Segue sugestão de conversão para o seu código; avalie-a com cuidado, pois não foi testada.

```
-- código #3
SELECT ...
  from  AEMANUTE as MN
        inner join AFENTIDADE on AFENTIDADE.CODENTIDADE = MN.CODENTIDADE
        left outer join AREGDOC as R on R.CODAO = M.CODAO and R.numfact = MN.numfact
        inner join AESERVICO on aeservico.numfolha = MN.numfolha
        inner join UTILIZADORES on utilizadores.codutilizador = aeservico.codutilizador
        inner join AIAREAORGANICA on AIAREAORGANICA.CODAO = MN.CODAO
  where UTILIZADORES.ANULADO IS NULL 
        and (R.coddoc is null or R.coddoc = 'FM')
        and (R.STATUS is null or R.STATUS <> 'E')
        and MN.IdSituacao = 5
        and LEFT(MN.datafecho, 10) >='2017-04-01' And LEFT(MN.datafecho, 10)  <='2017-04-30' 
  order by NOMEAO, NOMEUTILIZADOR, AFENTIDADE.NOMEENTIDADE;
```

---

Sugestão de leitura

- [Old Join Syntax vs. New](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/old-join-syntax-vs-new)

Comment: Muito Obrigada, deu pra entender melhor e assim ,consegui passa-la para linq to sql

Comment: @Magna não esqueça de aceitar a resposta, caso ela tenha lhe ajudado, para que outros usuários com a mesma dúvida possam se beneficiar da sua pergunta no futuro